# Android app to repeat what microphone records after a short pause

Tags: android, microphone, repeater, loopback, discord

Can someone please recommend an Android app (preferably free) to record a few seconds of audio and play it back after about a second of silence?

Discord's Web app on PC has settings > Voice & Video > MIC TEST > Let's Check but on the latest Chrome and Firefox on Android, it states "Unsupported browser". Its Android app does not have the Mic Test.

Comment: See my comment on your other question: https://superuser.com/questions/1837002/android-app-to-play-back-a-sound-snippet-after-microphone-records-some-sound