# Android app to play back a sound snippet after microphone records some sound

Tags: android, microphone, voice

Can someone please recommend an Android app (preferably free) to play a user-configurable sound file on hearing a few seconds of speech followed by about a second of silence?

I cannot use a smart speaker as the utterances are not prefaced by a wake-word, and are in an unsupported language.

Bonus points if it can choose different responses based on how closely it matches some sample utterances.

Comment: Please note that both of your questions are very much off topic on this site. Questions about Android products are off topic here, as are questions specifically asking for recommendations of hardware or software. This is spelled out rather clearly in the Help section, which I recommend that you review.